# Apple Music - Receiving Error 9,039 Constantly When Adding Music to Library

Tags: macos, itunes, catalina, error, apple-music

Since updating my iOS to Catalina (10.15.7), every time I add music to my library from Apple Music I receive Error 9,039 and the selection is not added to my library.  I have tried several recommended solutions, including signing in and out of Apple Music, unsyncing and resyncing my library, selecting "Update Cloud library," reauthorizing my computer, and manually clearing the Apple Music folders in my Cache.  Some of these solutions worked briefly, but the problem would return within an hour or two.  Is there anything else that I could try to resolve this?

Comment: Have you talked to AppleSupport?

Comment: Not yet, trying that today.  but other post who've had the same problem said that Support wasn't helpful :/

Comment: they were no help.  my 2013 computer is "vintage," apparently